# What criteria should I look for to publish my cemetery records online?

Tags: australia, cemeteries, burial-records, transcriptions

I have several complete cemetery headstone transcriptions and some additional partial cemeteries.
None appear to be indexed online. What criteria from free sites or free content on paid sites should I consider, so they are  available to all for the future? They are:

- small, mostly now unused Australian cemeteries
- visited for my own research
- documented the details on each headstone
- some have photographs

Comment: Please clarify what is intended by "complete cemetery headstone transcriptions." Do these represent a body of work that you developed about complete (specific) cemeteries at some point in time? Are they published materials or worksheets that someone else developed? The names/identities of the cemeteries would be helpful.

Comment: These are small, mostly now unused cemeteries that I have visited for my own research. Due to the small number of graves, I try to document the details on each headstone. Where practical, I also photograph. In addition, I have details of specific families at other cemeteries. The ones I am currently querying are not name indexed as far as I can find.

Answer (score 23):

One possible online site is http://www.interment.net/. They accept whole and partial cemetery listings, but give preference to whole listings.

Answer (score 22):

I really like [Find-a-Grave](https://www.findagrave.com)'s functionality

- submit a whole cemetery (5 or more individuals at a time, by spreadsheet upload) or add memorials one at a time
- add pictures, biographies, transcripts, identify grave location
- link memorials of spouses, parents & children
- transfer management of individual memorials to persons more closely related to the deceased
- collaboration with others to improve a memorial page regardless of the page's ownership
- modify a cemetery's profile page with specific information (location, history)
- discouragement of duplicates
- visibility in [Google](https://www.google.com) and as a database at [Ancestry](https://ancestry.com) and [MyHeritage](https://www.myheritage.com) etc.
- global scope
- ongoing site improvements in search capability, such as the added options for names, plots, contributors, and upgrades to the geographic names.

However, the Findagrave has some idiosyncrasies. The placename database uses modern hierarchies and some historic placenames are omitted (these can be referenced in the bio section). Also, the individual memorial pages make it harder to see the cemetery as a whole.
As alternatives, check with the local genealogical or historical societies to see if their websites will host the material.
Also, check the appropriate GenWeb sites to see if they are have similar transcripts.
Examples (from Canada)

- [Elgin County Cemetery Transcriptions of Gravestones](https://elgin.ogs.on.ca/ancestor-indexes/cemetery-transcriptions/)
- [CanadaGenWeb's Cemetery Project](https://cemetery.canadagenweb.org/)

If you choose to place the material in multiple places, it may be possible to cross-reference the sites.

Comment: Congratulations on not only answering the immediate question (Which site?) but also setting out the criteria that make this an appropriate choice. It is that second element that will give this response on-going value to future readers.

Comment: Agreeing with @Fortiter here -- good list of criteria.

Comment: I do prefer Find-a-grave (even though I was appalled when Ancestry bought them).  Much better than interment.net or billiongraves.com  BillionGraves app changed the lat/long on four entries I made to be five miles away and then refused to correct it.  I agree completely with everything bgwiehle said, including the negatives.

Answer (score 7):

I use [Find a Grave](http://www.findagrave.com/) as it is a very active site. (see @bgwiehle answer for more details)

Or you can use [BillionGraves](http://billiongraves.com/) from your mobile phone.

Answer (score 6):

I would send it to archive.org first. They seem to have a very liberal policy about holding useful data for a very long time.

Then, after that, send it to other sites. Perhaps you could send them a link to your archive.org collection so they have easy access to it.

Comment: archive.org will hold onto the data, but it won't be very findable there.

Comment: Good point. The main reason I suggested this is to reduce the chance that it gets lost before another site  integrates it. I'd hate for a hard drive failure to happen while waiting for a response from a third party.

Comment: I agree: the IA is likely to be around longer than any of the grave-cataloguing sites.

Comment: Another advantage of Find-a-grave: you can get the info online and do it right before it gets added by one of the many people who can't seem to _see_ the instructions findagrave puts on the entry form.  :-)  As far as survival, Findagrave is now owned by Ancestry.com and BillionGraves by the Mormons.  I don't expect either to fade away very soon.